# Ray task in nested loop results in out of memory

Tags: python, out-of-memory, ray

I'm trying to run a ray task in nested loop.
Each loop takes dataA which has 5000 rows of list.
In ray task, it takes dataB and dataC that are 5000 x 256, 5000 x 768 respectively.
Whenever ray task runs, out of memory error occurs and then worker gets killed with below implementation.
How can I avoid this error?

```
import ray
import os

num_cpu = os.cpu_count()
ray.init(num_cpus=num_cpu)

dataB = ray.put(dataB)    # 5000 x 256
dataC = ray.put(dataC)    # 5000 x 768

@ray.remote
def calculate(dataB, dataC):
    calcResult = someCalculationWithDataBAndC()
    return calcResult

for i in range(len(dataA)):
    for j in range(i + 1, len(dataA), 1):
        resultList = [calculate.remote(dataB, dataC, i, j)]

resultList = ray.get(resultList)

ray.shutdown()
```

Comment: why [calculate.remote(dataB, dataC, i, j)] get 4 parameters but def calculate(dataB, dataC): if two